# JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'activate' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, uwp, windows-store-apps

I get the following error:

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'activate' of undefined or null reference

when running the following line of javascript in my UWP App:

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.activate();
Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.current.activate();
```

or

```
Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.activate();
```

[API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.window#Windows_UI_Xaml_Window_Activate), [Handle app activation Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/activate-an-app)

Comment: That means `Windows.UI.Xaml.Window` is undefined. This is basically a NPE. You may need to initialize something first before `Xaml.Window` becomes available.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Weird is that if I only run `Windows.UI.Xaml.Window` I get no exception.

Comment: Because `Windows.UI.Xaml.Window` does nothing. It evaluates to `undefined`, which isn't an error by itself. You're trying to call a function on `undefined` though, which is an error.

Comment: Do you know what a NullPointerException is in Java?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think that is the case here. Firstly, because the Docs do not mention a need for initialization. Secondly, because it gets initialized by default -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.window (see #Remarks, first & fourth paragraph)

Comment: Well, evidently it's not being initialized. I don't know that specific API, but because of the error, I know that `Windows.UI.Xaml.Window` is `undefined` (or `null`).

Comment: And that appears to be a C# API reference. Are you sure that applies to JS?

Comment: Is this even intended for JS? Are you importing anything? What's the value of `Windows`?

Comment: `Windows` is a namespace

Comment: And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml), if you set `javascript` in the sidebar on the right hand side, the `Window` class gets listed.

Comment: Sorry, idk. But your problem is that `Window` is undefined. Try running `console.log(Windows.UI.Xaml)` in a debugger browser. See what properties it exposes that you can use.

Comment: Consider that the code is being used in an UWP App. And not in a normal Web Browser.

Comment: There should be some way of inspecting `Windows.UI.Xaml` in the environment you're using. The point is to see what `XAML` contains.

Comment: I did that, and it contains a lot ... - Should I append that to the question?

Comment: I'd say including as much information about your debugging attempts as possible is a good thing. Sorry, I've exhausted my ideas. Good luck.

Comment: The Windows.UI.Xaml namespace is not available in js. What do you try to achieve by these calls?

Comment: @TheTanic I am trying to put the applications window in the foreground (if it is not) from inside a jvascript function that starts when the application has been started :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows.Ui.Xaml and the docs you linked aren't relevant for HTML/JavaScript apps. Windows.UI.Xaml is used only in Xaml apps.

To call activate You need a Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow object, but Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow itself is logically a class not an object

You need to create or acquire an instance of the class to call activate. To get such an object call CoreWindow's static method [getForCurrentThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow#Windows_UI_Core_CoreWindow_GetForCurrentThread)

```
var window = Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.getForCurrentThread();
Window.activate();
```

That said, what problem are you actually trying to solve? Why are you calling this? Initial window activation in JavaScript apps is handled by framework code not called explicitly by app code. Unless you're managing multiple CoreWindows in your app, attempts to activate the window will depend on it already being active: you can't force your window on the user.

Comment: The problem seems to be that `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow` is undefined because I still get the error: `0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'getForCurrentThread' of undefined or null reference
`

Comment: Why are you trying to call this and where? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I try to (at least) check whether the window is activated or not using the [`activated` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow#Windows_UI_Core_CoreWindow_Activated). Or, if possible, put the window in the foreground. All of that, because I am calling specific API's that are only allowed when calling them from the foreground :)

Comment: It looks like CoreWindow isn't projected into JavaScript, but you don't need it for what you're trying on two accounts: 1) you can track focus with window.onfocus 2) you can't force your app into the foreground. It's not clear what you're trying to do with the clipboard, but your questions suggest you're taking the wrong approach to it. I'd recommend asking a question with your actual scenario rather than targeting the small problems you're running into trying to get there