# UWP App - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'onclick' of undefined or null reference occurred

Tags: javascript, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I'm following this [Official MSDN tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/create-a-hello-world-app-js-uwp) to create my first [UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide). But when I run the app it gives me the following error on the first line of the onload() method in main.js file:

> > JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'onclick' of undefined or null reference occurred

I'm using [latest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/updates-and-versions/choose-a-uwp-version?ocid=VSClient_VerX_NewProject_version) Build 17134 (version 1803) of UWP on latest version of `VS2017`. I doubt that MSDN will publish the tutorial without testing their code. So, maybe it's related to the build version and VS2017 versions since I'm using the latest versions and the tutorial is more than a year old.

I tried understanding the following SO posts but did not quite get. Maybe since I'm a newbie to UWP: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470746/javascript-runtime-error-unable-to-get-property-activate-of-undefined-or-null) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655348/getting-0x800a138f-javascript-runtime-error-unable-to-get-property-client-o). **Question**: What maybe the cause of the error and how to fix it?

**Inded.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>WUP_TestSep2018</title>
    <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>Content goes here!
    <p>Click the button...</p>
    <button id="buttonID">Hello World</button>
    </div>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = function (evt) {
        sayHello()
    }
}

function sayHello() {
    var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Hello, world!", "Alert");
    messageDialog.showAsync();
}
```

Comment: You have no element whose `id` is `button`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thank you for catching my typo and also responding so quickly.After reading your comment and correcting my typo it works now.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("button")` object does not have an "onclick" property.

You wrote the wrong id.

`document.getElementById("button")`

->

```
document.getElementById("buttonID")
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: @NarendraJadhav Why you think, that this isnt an answer to the problem?

Comment: @TheTanic Because it's not the solution.  OP did mistake to use wrong `id` instead of right.  for more details please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This should be in comment not answer.@TheTanic

Answer (score 0):

In your index.html, you declare a button by id of "buttonId":

```
<button id="buttonId">Hello world</button>
```

but in your javascript you try to retrieve it by

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function...
```

What happens if you try to

```
document.getElementById("buttonId").onclick = function...
```

Basically what happens in the original code is that document.getElementById() function returns undefined because no such id exists. You then try to setup onclick property of undefined.